# changing Tab with intent from notification

Tags: java, android

I hava a TabHost Activity with 2 tabs. Additionally my application has basicly 2 different types of notification. Now I want to open Tab 1 with a click on notification 1 and Tab 2 with a click on notification 2. So I put a extra to the notification intent with an ID, which represents the Tab's ID. To change Tabs i tried to get the ID in the onResume method of the TabHost Activity with getIntent().getExtra(...) and change the Tab. This solution works in most cases. However it sometimes does not work properly, but I dont know why. Any clue why it sometimes works and sometimes not? Or is there maybe a better solution to solve this problem?